# Create Excel Chart within Excel File

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am exporting some data from my system. I want to visualize these datasets in an excel chart. I have found and old, closed question, where the solution was missing. The charts should redraw when i change a datafield, this is excel standard, i guess.

I think it may work this way:

- export Data
- create manually a chart with MS-Excel
- save and load this as a template in all other future exports

Do you know how to do it with POI using Java? Especially the import of the chart as template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till now as the [apache POI limitation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) is saying **"You can not currently create charts. You can however create a chart in Excel, modify the chart data values using HSSF and write a new spreadsheet out. This is possible because POI attempts to keep existing records intact as far as possible".**

However in my case, I have created a chart manually on excel sheet using Named Ranges, and using java, I am updating named ranges as per my requirement. Since the chart is based on named ranges so it also get updated.

For updation please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17706504/624003)

Comment: Thanks Sankumarsingh, i have always created the excel-docs from scratch with poi. Could you please explain, how to load an existing .xls-File ?

Comment: Loading is as simple as creating. You can take help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709121/624003

Answer (score 2):

POI doesn't give you that functionality but You can convert or copy charts(graphs) using J XL or Aspose Cells(Aspose is not free).

This is the code snippet to extract excel chart to image

```
public class ExportChartToImage
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //Start Excel
        Application excelApp = new Application();
        excelApp.setVisible(true);

        //Create test workbook
        Workbook workbook = excelApp.createWorkbook("/home/tejus/Desktop/Chart Test");

        //Get the first (and the only) worksheet
        final Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

        //Fill-in the first worksheet with sample data
        worksheet1.getCell("A1").setValue("Date");
        worksheet1.getCell("A2").setValue("March 1");
        worksheet1.getCell("A3").setValue("March 8");
        worksheet1.getCell("A4").setValue("March 15");

        worksheet1.getCell("B1").setValue("Customer");
        worksheet1.getCell("B2").setValue("Smith");
        worksheet1.getCell("B3").setValue("Jones");
        worksheet1.getCell("B4").setValue("James");

        worksheet1.getCell("C1").setValue("Sales");
        worksheet1.getCell("C2").setValue("23");
        worksheet1.getCell("C3").setValue("17");
        worksheet1.getCell("C4").setValue("39");

        excelApp.getOleMessageLoop().doInvokeAndWait(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                final Variant unspecified = Variant.createUnspecifiedParameter();
                final Int32 localeID = new Int32(LocaleID.LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT);

                Range sourceDataNativePeer = worksheet1.getRange("A1:C4").getPeer();
                _Worksheet worksheetNativePeer = worksheet1.getPeer();

                IDispatch chartObjectDispatch = worksheetNativePeer.chartObjects(unspecified, localeID);

                ChartObjectsImpl chartObjects = new ChartObjectsImpl(chartObjectDispatch);
                ChartObject chartObject = chartObjects.add(new DoubleFloat(100), new DoubleFloat(150), new DoubleFloat(300), new DoubleFloat(225));

                _Chart chart = chartObject.getChart();
                chart.setSourceData(sourceDataNativePeer, new Variant(XlRowCol.xlRows));

                BStr fileName = new BStr("/home/tejus/Desktop/chart.gif");
                Variant filterName = new Variant("gif");
                Variant interactive = new Variant(false);

                chart.export(fileName, filterName, interactive);

                chart.setAutoDelete(false);
                chart.release();

                chartObject.setAutoDelete(false);
                chartObject.release();

                chartObjects.setAutoDelete(false);
                chartObjects.release();

                chartObjectDispatch.setAutoDelete(false);
                chartObjectDispatch.release();
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Press 'Enter' to terminate the application");
        System.in.read();

        //Close the MS Excel application.
        boolean saveChanges = false;
        workbook.close(saveChanges);
        boolean forceQuit = true;
        excelApp.close(forceQuit);
    }

}
```

i used J excel