# Reading 'name' used in cell of excel sheet via POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.9 for parsing excel file.
In one of the cell which I am trying to read 'Name' has been used in the formula specified for this cell (formula is sum of value at name cell + value of current cell). These names have been defined in 'Name manager' of excel.
When I am trying to read this value via POI I am getting 'circular`ref'.
Can anyone please advise me on how to read the value of the formula cell where 'name' is used?

Thanks

Comment: Go through http://stackoverflow.com/a/17706504/624003. This will help you to understand how to read name ranges and update that.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.This link was useful.I want to read the value for the name as defined in Name manager

Comment: What exactly you want? the formula that the name is defined to refer to or anything else.

Comment: when you click on Name Manager in the excel, we can see Name,value,Refers To,Scope and comment for each Name which is defined.I want to retrieve the value for the name which is defined in this name manager.
Hope I was able to convey what I need.